# Using data from an ajax call in Flask routes

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Hello I'd like to use data obtained from an ajax call in a Flask route. Please see tan example below. The app get and print the data correctly in the *button_val()* but won't flash any value in the *test()*: why?

Thank you in advance

**Flask app**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request 

class dataStore():
    y = None
data = dataStore()    

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_button_val') 
def button_val():
  resp = request.args.get('resp')
  print(f'<-- {resp}')
  data.y = resp
  return resp    

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if data.y == 11:
            flash('a')
        if data.y == 10:
            flash('b')  
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Buttons via AJAX</h2>
        <button class="button1" data="11">Yes</button>
        <button class="button2" data="10">No</button>
            
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.button1, .button2').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var val = $(this).attr('data');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/get_button_val',
                        data: { resp: val },
                        success: onSuccess,
                        error: onError,
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

  {% for msg in get_flashed_messages()%}
  <h3>   {{msg}} </h3> 
  {% endfor%}
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct behavior. Under `test`, you are only flashing a value when there is a `POST` call to that route and nowhere in your code do you have such a call.

You load the page, and that is a `GET`. This returns your template and is what loads your page.

Updated (because I misread a part of your code)

After your page loads, it waits for the user to click any of the buttons at which point it makes a `GET` call to `/get_button_val`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. so please what should I do to flash this value once the page is loaded (and without the need to reload it)? Thank you

Comment: Forget the code for now and think of your logic. Your logic is - user enters a url (GET) and this loads the page which has 2 buttons each with a value. Based on this, why exactly do you want to flash a value to the user, where is the value coming from? Is it better to just display the value directly as part of the page? You need to sort out your logic first and then the code will follow

Comment: Thanks, I was using the flash only to see if I get the buttons' values. The idea is that the next stimulus (e.g., question) will be determined by which button was pressed -  a loop. Unfortunately, this next stimulus has to be generated within Python. Thanks.